# Angular ui-calendar => How to use gotoDate?

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui-router

What I want is, when I open the scheduling page, the calendar must show the date based on the date I supplied and the view must be in month view. So I came into a solution using fullcalendar's gotoDate function. But the problem is it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

**controller**

```
if($stateParams.displayedDate != '') {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', $stateParams.displayedDate);
}
```

**view**

```
<div id="calendar" ui-calendar="calendarConfig" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

Well, the code above didn't work so I tried another approach. I changed some codes in my controller

```
if($stateParams.displayedDate != '') {
    $scope.calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $stateParams.displayedDate);
}
```

but an error occured saying something like "calling a function from undefined object ...... etc ..."

I'm using, angularJS 1.2, angular ui-calendar 1.0, fullcalendar 2.3.1

**Note:** I supply $stateParams with date in this format "YYYY-MM-DD"  *eg. 2015-02-15*

**EDIT UPDATE**

It seems that I can't access the calendar object. So following the documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#accessing-the-calendar-object I ended my code into this

**controller**

```
$scope.uiCalendarConfig = {
    calendar: {
        height: 720,
        editable: true,
        forceEventDuration: true,
        header:{
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prevYear prev today next nextYear'
        },
        viewRender: currentCalendarDisplayInfo,
        eventDrop: $scope.saveTrainingSchedule,
        eventResize: $scope.saveTrainingSchedule
    }
};

if($stateParams.displayedDate != '') {
    $scope.uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $stateParams.displayedDate);
// console.log($scope.myCalendar); -> returns undefined
// console.log($scope.uiCalendarConfig); -> there is no "calendars" object
}
```

**view**

```
<div ui-calendar="uiCalendarConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
```

But still didn't work. Can somebody give me a step by step process? I can't really follow what the docs is saying.

I tried to *console.log($scope.myCalendar);* but it is undefined then tried *console.log($scope.uiCalendarConfig.calendar);* and there is no **calendars** object in it.

**UPDATE 2**

I'm getting close. So I just have to inject **uiCalendarConfig** in my controller and then it will be avaialble but I still got a problem. console.log(uiCalendarConfig.calendars); returns an emptyObject.

**controller**

```
var controllers = {};

controllers.trainingScheduleController = function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $http, uiCalendarConfig, utilityFunctions) {

    if($stateParams.displayedDate != '') {
        console.log(uiCalendarConfig.calendars); // returns Object{}
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $stateParams.displayedDate); // error -> calling function from undefined
    }



    $scope.calendarConfig = {
        height: 720,
        editable: true,
        forceEventDuration: true,
        header:{
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'prevYear prev today next nextYear'
        },
        viewRender: currentCalendarDisplayInfo,
        eventDrop: $scope.saveTrainingSchedule,
        eventResize: $scope.saveTrainingSchedule
    };


};

manageTrainingsModule.controller(controllers);
```

**view**

```
<div ui-calendar="calendarConfig" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
```

Comment: Please remove the second question from your question. Unless I'm misreading something, it's a new issue, and so should be asked separately.

Comment: No. Its the same issue Im asking. Its still about how to use Full Calendar's gotoDate function with Angular ui-calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the lib's source code seems like you won't have direct access to the instance from the view, so you have to do two things:

- inject "uiCalendarConfig" in your controller. This variable will be an object with the "calendars" attribute. In this attribute there's another object with the calendar instances. The name of your instance is determined by an attribute in the view, "calendar".
- add an attribute "calendar" in the view to name your instance.

So, if you have a code like this:

```
<div ui-calendar="calendarConfig" calendar="myCalendar"/>
```

In the controller the calendar instance will be:

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar;
```

See more in the source:

```
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/master/src/calendar.js
```

**UPDATE:**

You are getting it wrong. Based on your updated, you will keep the HTML as it is now, but in the controller you want to do like this:

```
function TheController($scope, uiCalendarConfig) {
  $scope.calendarConfig = {
    height: ...
  };

  console.log(uiCalendarConfig);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. so my problem is this. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#accessing-the-calendar-object

Comment: I updated my question. I've added my current progress . So could you help me to identify whats' the wrong in my code?

Comment: Yey, I'm getting closer. But console.log(uiCalendarConfig.calendars); returns an empty object. So using uiCalendar.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', '2015-8-12'); returns an error ("cant read fullCalendar property of undefiined")

Comment: When I console.log(uiCalendarConfig); I can see uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar. Well I think my problem now is, I dont know how to use it for fulcalendar functions. I guess I will have to open another question about this because its a little off topic.

Comment: Thnaks sir. Your a big help.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use defaultDate in [fullCalendar config](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/)

Comment: The problem is how would I use it. I tried $('#calendar').fullCalendar('defaultDate', '2015-08-01'); but it didnt worked. It seems that I can't use fullcalendar's functions like that since I'm using angular ui-calendar

Answer (score 0):

Try changeing

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $stateParams.displayedDate);
```

to

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('gotoDate', $stateParams.displayedDate);
```

That solved my issue.

Comment: Those two lines are equivalent.